# What is the name of the condition where you feel like you have been somewhere before?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory

It happens many times when you visit a place you have never been before, you feel `subconsciously` you have been there already. And the events and people you are meeting and experiencing have already taken place sometimes back and you are just `re-experiencing` it.

What is this condition called? Is there any scientific study on the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term is typically called déjà vu..

There's a [section on wikipedia discussing scientific research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu#Scientific_research).

Brown (2003) looks like a good starting point for a more rigorous scientific analysis.

Kusumi (2006, [PDF](http://www.educ.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cogpsy/personal/Kusumi/dejavu.pdf)) has another scientific review article on the topic.

#### References

- Brown, A. S. (2003). A review of the déjà vu experience. Psychological bulletin, 129(3), 394.
- Kusumi, T. (2006). Human metacognition and the déjà vu phenomenon. Diversity in cognition: Evolution, development, domestication, and pathology, 302-314.
  http://www.educ.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cogpsy/personal/Kusumi/dejavu.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is more appropriate as a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation at the moment.  Jeromy Anglim's answer is excellent but I thought I'd mention that the term was missing the diacritic marks, or pronunciation symbols above the e and a: déjà vu.

This viral video by vsauce is excellent and entertaining, so I thought it was worth mentioning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSf8i8bHIns

This video by TED-Ed is also excellent in it's depiction and description of déjà vu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foVMwJtlR5s